# Matching names with underscore in DapperPlus

Tags: c#, dapper

In Dapper there is Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true; to match a column name with underscore to the corresponding property name in the c# class.
Is there something equivalent with DapperPlus?
Thank you.

I cant find anything online nor in DapperPlus documentation.

Comment: DapperPlus has nothing to do with [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper). Someone hijacked Dapper's name, set up a supposed "documentation" site full of errors and then started selling "extensions" using another library's name. Not the first time either. If you bought it, ask the author for help. If not .... At least, if that thing is still built on top of Dapper, you can use Dapper's configuration

Comment: You should keep in mind that those "extensions" aren't what they claim. There's no BULK UPDATE or BULK MERGE in SQL Server, and the only way to execute BULK INSERT, is through SqlBulkCopy. BULK INSERT isn't just a multi-row insert, it uses minimal logging, only logging entire data pages instead of individual rows. To perform a multi-row update or "merge" without actually adding multiple values, you have to either pass the data as a table-valued parameter (not very scalable, requires database changes) or insert the data into a temp/staging table first, then update the target table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently looking for the `UseSmartMatchNames` options in Dapper Plus:

```
connection.UseBulkOptions(x => x.UseSmartMatchNames = true).BulkInsert(list);
DapperPlusManager.Entity<EntitySimples>().UseBulkOptions(x => x.UseSmartMatchNames = true);
```

This option will support underscore `_` and dot `.` in the column name